# Furniture name for waist-high floor-sitting shelf cabinet thing

Tags: furniture, terminology

I'm working on this thing (60" wide x 41.75" high [elbow height] x 14" deep) (shelves on left and right are adjustable, I might ditch the little border thing on top):

[image]

It's purpose is general storage near an entry way, the top will primarily be used for mail, documents, etc. The large space is for storage baskets.

When I try to tell people what I'm making, I find that I'm saying "it's this shelf sort of table-y storage thing on the floor, or something, or... whatever, let's talk about something else".

Now, I've seen furniture like this before. Cabinets that sit on the floor with shelves and stuff and a waist/elbow high top. My question is, what are these called? I want to say "I am building a _______."

I went through Wikipedia's [list of furniture types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_furniture_types) but I couldn't find it. There are "entertainment centers", but that's not actually what this is for, and it's a little high even if I were going to put entertainment stuff on it. It's *kind of* like a [sideboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideboard), maybe? It's not a dresser, there's no drawers.

I'm sure this has a name I just don't know what it is.

Comment: It doesn't really fit any traditional furniture categories, as it's purpose is modern in function. It is closest to a hall tree I would say, only missing somewhere to hang your coat and hat essentially. If it were me I would call it what it is functionally, perhaps foyer cabinet, or mud room cabinet, as it really is by definition a cabinet first, and then can be further defined by its location, and then function.

Comment: Look's like a non-TV TV hutch. I mean, add a shelf in that big open space!

Comment: @Raystafarian Ha, well, the open space is for some storage baskets. But actually, I might as well put some shelf pin holes in there just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call that a *[credenza](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/credenza)*:

> A sideboard, buffet, or bookcase patterned after a Renaissance credence; especially: one without legs

Wikipedia [adds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credenza):

> particularly one where a central cupboard is flanked by quadrant glass display cabinets

which I might generalize to "central cupboard flanked by shelves", I'm not sure I'd require "glass display cabinets".  Looking through [Google images](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=credenza&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj66ITxnJ_QAhXo8YMKHVY6AsQQ_AUICSgC&biw=1139&bih=812#tbm=isch&q=credenza&chips=q:credenza,g_1:victorian), that seems to apply mostly to Victorian-styled cabinets.

[image]

They're typically lower than your 41" height, but that's otherwise a credenza.  Historically, they were used to hold food and utensils for serving in a dining room, but they're now common as an office storage add-on to a main desk or a decorative/storage cabinet that goes against a wall, and is not mounted under a counter or as an end table.

Comment: Oh yeah! [That looks like the winner](https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=credenza). Those are totally what I was thinking of. It seems it is relatively uncommon but not unusual to have them be legless. The large area in the center of mine is ultimately going to be used for storage baskets, which are sort of drawer-like and move it even more into credenza territory. Although, stuff like [this](http://images2.imgix.net/p4dbimg/5/images/5091-85001.jpg?fit=fill&bg=FFFFFF) is really making me feel inadequate now, heh.

Answer (score 3):

There are moments when it is incumbent upon a modern people to invent new terms :)

I suggest "entry hutch".

Comment: "Hutch" on Wikipedia shows something kind of sort of very much like the design from OP

Comment: Haha, or a good old "floor hutch". If/when I add "entry hutch" to Wikipedia can I cite this post as maybe sort of like a source?

Comment: @JasonC Of course! I'll warm up my best authoritative voice :)  But of course adoption of terms takes some time, so might be a bit of a wait to see if this one would gain any traction :)